# jQuery size() and find if class is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, size

I'm trying to count the li's of a ul. I am using jQuery size() method.

Here is a sample of my HTML:

```
<ul id="show-items" class="ui-sortable">
    <li id="todo-2">
        <label class="editable done">fasdfasdf</label>
    </li>
    <li id="todo-3">
        <label class="editable">fasdfasdf</label>
    </li>
    <li id="todo-4">
        <label class="editable">fasdfasdf</label>
    </li>
    <li id="todo-5">
        <label class="editable done">fasdfasdf</label>
    </li>
    <li id="todo-6">
        <label class="editable">fasdfasdf</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I use the following code to find all the lists from #show-items but **I want to specify only the lists which have label and class done and the lists which haven't got class done.**

```
var n = $("#show-items li").size();
          $(".numb").text("There are " + n + " divs. Click to add more.");
```

This show's me the lists which have the class done:

```
var n = $("#show-items li").find(".done").size();
          $(".numb").text("Clear " + n + " completed task.");
```

How can I find the lists with no class done? I tried `:not(done)` but it show's my everything else apart from the lists.

So basically from the above HTML I want to get this:

*You have 5 lists. 2 Lists have class done and 3 don't.*

Thanks alot

Comment: Call me silly, but isn't it simple math if you know your total and the number done, to figure out the number not done (assuming it has to be one or the other).

Comment: @gregp Well it is but in the future I want to be calling only once, the lists with no class done. And since it should be a line of code id rather skip maths. Thats the reason I asked the question in the first place

Comment: Didn't mean anything negative by my comment, just observing. In terms of cycles, you always need to get the total number (the initial jQuery object). From there, no matter whether you search for the "done" or the "no done class", you always have the inverse with one simple line of math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  You can use the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector like so:

```
// <li> without .done class on <label>
$("#show-items li").find("label:not(.done)").size();

// <li> with .done class on <label>
$("#show-items li").find("label.done").size();
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zsbT8/1/).

Comment: Thanks alot. I was trying this: $("#show-items li").find(":not(.done)").size(); and wasn't working. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Even easier and **faster**:

```
alert($("#show-items li label:not(.done)").size());
alert($("#show-items li label.done").size());
```

you don't have to use `find()` after a selector.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zsbT8/2/

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to use the length property instead of size(). As the jQuery docs say:

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length >property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

http://api.jquery.com/size/

http://api.jquery.com/length/